# Why does Anaconda still try to download package even though I manually put them into the package cache?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

[image]

My goal is to create a Python 3.6 environment. My internet is not stable, so I pre-downloaded the necessary packages manually and placed them in the package cache (`~/anaconda3/pkgs`).

Here are the steps I took:

- (step 1 in the picture ) Before I run `conda create -n test python=3.6`, I make sure the package is in place, namely, the **python-3.6.9-h256db76_0.conda** already exists in `~/anaconda3/pkgs`
- (step 2 in the picture) After running `conda create -n test python=3.6`, Conda provides me with the transaction plan to review, and it shows that it still wants to download the `python-3.6.9` package. I proceed with yes.
- (step 3 in the picture) Conda renames the existing **python-3.6.9-h256db76_0.conda** to **python-3.6.9-h256db76_0.conda.c~**. and begins to redownload the package.

My question is:

- Why does Conda try to download existing packages?
- How can I configure Conda to use a local package cache, if my internet is unstable?

here is conda configuration:

```
(tf15) hhw@hhw-002:~/datadisk/my_stock_model$ conda config --show | grep pkgs
  pkgs/main: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/r: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/pro: https://repo.anaconda.com
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
pkgs_dirs:
  - /home/hhw/anaconda3/pkgs
  - /home/hhw/.conda/pkgs
```

Comment: are you sure `~/anaconda3/pkgs` is the default directory for installing conda packages ?

Comment: @YOLO, I put configuration of conda on the question.

Comment: I think you can try using `--use-local`, play with the parameters: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html

Comment: add  --use-local don't work. the situation is same.